# Center of a circle from two chords.

Tags: geometry, circles

If two chords of a circle intersect and are $\perp$ to each other, is it possible to find the distance from the intersection point of the chords to the center?

I was trying to use the power of a point argument.

Comment: I want to show it for any such chords, not a specific one.

Comment: I understand that but we can still find a general formula. Remember that given any two intersecting chords we can establish a relationship with them using the power of an interior point.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you then. Its just given that there two chords inside a circle that intersect but are also $\perp$ to each other.

Comment: If you have two segments $AB$ and $CD$ then lets say they intersect at a point $K$. When they intersect, the chords can be thought of as being broken into two sections each. Then the product of the sections of one chord is equal to the product of the sections of the other chord. Didnt know if I could use this argument at all.

Comment: **Hint:** The point of the intersection of the mediating bisectors of the two cords is the center of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Draw congruent chords parallel to those you have, and get this symmetric picture.

[image]

The central rectangle has width $AB-2BK$ and height $CD-2CK$. The center of the circle is at the intersection of the rectangle's diagonals, so the distance from $K$ to the center is half the length of a diagonal of the rectangle, or $\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{(AB-2BK)^2+(CD-2CK)^2}$

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, it is possible.

[image]

The general outline of finding the distance $KO$ is this:

Given the lengths $AK, BK, CK$, and $DK$, use the Pythagorean Theorem to find the lengths of the sides of cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ and use Theorem 2 in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102680/two-theorems-about-an-inscribed-quadrilateral-and-the-radius-of-the-circle-conta) question to find the radius of the circle.

Once you have that, you can find the length of the perpendicular line from $AB$ passing through $O$. By Pythagoras, this is equal to
$$m=\sqrt{r^2-\left(\frac{AK+BK}{2}\right)^2}$$
and, in turn, you can find $KO$ by using Pythagoras once again:
$$KO=\sqrt{m^2+\left(\frac{AK-BK}{2}\right)^2}$$